# Help designing a thing to do with micro wind generation MPPT

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mppt

Firstly, be gentle with me - I'm about at the watts=voltsxamps level, I've had an idea but need help.

Is there anyone with an interest in MPPT (more like MPP in fact) controllers? What I would like to do is let my turbine operate at 60v+ while charging my battery at 48-56v.

Why? Because I have noticed a big increase in watts from the turbine when my genny is holding the battery up around 60v. It likes the higher voltage. There is a commercial product for this, a tracking MPPT by Midnite but it is £625, can't afford that but mention it as they claim it increases output of wind by 50-200%.

I believe I need a DC-DC converter (but sure it isn't that simple) - it could be fixed at the wind end, wouldn't need to track. I can't find one that does (say) 70vDC - 60vDC

Ideally I'd like to be able to adjust the voltage on the wind side, but it doesn't need to track.

Thanks!

Comment: Can U define generator range in voltage and power or range of RPM with current and voltage?

Answer (score 1):

I think the rule for MPPT in turbines is:
$$ \tau = k * \omega^2 $$
where 'τ' is torque, 'k' is a constant you have to pick empirically and 'ω' is the rotational speed (rpm or whatever you have).

So your control system has to somehow set the torque based on this equation. Since generator current is proportional to torque, one way to do this would be to substitute current in the above equation.
$$I = k2 * \omega^2$$

where 'I' is the generator current, 'k2' is a different constant from 'k' and 'ω' is the rotational speed.

Use a PID control loop to vary the output voltage (or battery charge current) while monitoring the generator current to achieve the desired setpoint.

I am assuming you are using a permanent magnet generator, and that you don't have a field coil. Also, I have never done this before. But I am pretty sure that this is close to the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We know from the MPT Theorem that matched impedance transfers max power but losses must be considered for heat rise.

Grid Wind Power use constant RPM and vary impedance with prop pitch and converter load.  I suspect your turbine is variable speed over a limited range of 10:1 from cut-in speed so "no-load" voltage rises with RPM but drops from winding resistance, Rs * current, Is.

So how to compute the MPT load impedance?

I would use air speed , and voltage to regulate the current and sense all 3 variables such that the impedance rises from max power at some RPM and wind speed spec. from the (missing) datasheet to the no-load minimum air speed to cut-in at 0 power.  This relationship can be plotted to choose the optimum control design.

How to regulate converter / charger load impedance to match generator and wind power?

The easiest is use propeller tach to measure wind speed or regulate charger load with generator RPM sensing the pole current frequency during rotation.

Then regulate the charger to limit voltage with current load to battery then limit battery current when fully charged regulate excess power by shorting generator with PWM and and dump excess power into heaters or speed brakes.

But we need all the generator and battery specs to do anything.